# Javascript - Select text range from contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, select, html, text, range

I have this DIV and I want to select some text then, when pressing on some button, apply the bold style to it.

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<input type="button" id="bold" value="B" />
```

My JavaScript "works" like this

```
function CaretPosition(dom) {
    var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == dom) {
                caretPos = range.endOffset;
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        if (range.parentElement() == dom) {
            var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
            dom.insertBefore(tempEl, dom.firstChild);
            var tempRange = range.duplicate();
            tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
            tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
            caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
        }
    }
    return caretPos;
}

function SelectText(dom, start, end) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(dom.firstChild, start);
        range.setEnd(dom.lastChild, end);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(dom);
        range.select();
    }
}

var cp = 0;
var sp;

document.getElementById('editor').onkeyup = function() {
    cp = CaretPosition(document.getElementById('editor'));
    sp = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}

document.getElementById('editor').onmouseup = function() {
    cp = CaretPosition(document.getElementById('editor'));
    sp = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}

document.getElementById('bold').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('editor').focus();
    SelectText(document.getElementById('editor'), cp, sp);
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
```

Well, this code doesn't work and I'm trying to understand what could be wrong. I want it to be cross-browser. I think the problem lies in the `setStart` and `setEnd` arguments. Can anyone give me some clues?

**EXPECTED RESULT**
When I select some portion of text and click on the BOLD button, the selected text should change to bold.

**ACTUAL RESULT**
Looks like the `SelectText()` function doesn't select the text correctly, so when `execCommand` is called, it doesn't change the selected text. It changes other section of the text. It's like I don't send the correct start and end values, or something might be wrong with the `dom.firstChild`/`dom.lastChild`.
If I do this in my `SelectText()` function (change start by 2 and end by 6):

```
function SelectText(dom, start, end) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(dom.firstChild, 2);
        range.setEnd(dom.lastChild, 6);
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(dom);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

then, when I click once the text inside the DIV, from char 2 to 6 is selected and changed. When I click again, chars from 2 to 8 are selected and changed, and so on.

**UPDATE**
My last code can be tested at http://jsfiddle.net/wjjvH/15/

I managed to make it work on IE but not on other browsers. Also, I don't know how to find out the selection start and end so I can send them to the SelectText function.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: I updaed my question to answer yours, thanks.

Comment: The main problem is that, when you click (mouse is down) on anything other than `editor`, the focus is lost as well as the current selection. Thus, `getSelection` in the `SelectText` function will always return as no selection. You should save the current selection object to a global variable and use that instead of `getSelection`.

Comment: I updated my question. I could do that but it looks like the global variable selection empty itself when editor is unfocused. I posted my ode on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wjjvH/15/

Comment: You can use `mousedown` instead of `click` and prevent the browser's default action (i.e. nicking the focus) by adding `return false`: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/wjjvH/16/